# Ограничения компилятора в обобщениях

Tags: c#, .net, generics, компилятор

Зачем компилятор запрещает делать такие штуки как

```
interface II<out T>
{
    void M<V>() where V : T;
}
```

Хотя, если убрать ограничение `where V : T`, то компилятор позволит это скомпилировать

И второй пример

```
interface II<T>
{
    void M<V>() where V : T;
}

class A<T> : II<T>
{
    public void M<V>()// where V : T
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void II<T>.M<V>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Тут если убрать в классе **явную** реализацию, то компилятору захочется поругаться на то, что нет ограничения в неявной реализации. Почему? Откуда растут ноги у таких запретов компилятора? Зачем их ввели (желательно на примере, где видно, что без них было бы хуже)?

Comment: Первый пример: `II<string> o = ...`. Так нельзя `o.M<object>()`, а так можно `((II<object>)o).M<object()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема со второй частью очевидна.

Если у вас нет явной реализации, то метод `public void M<V>()` должен реализовать интерфейсный метод `void M<V>() where V : T`. Соответственно отсутствие ограничения будет нарушением.

Для *явной* реализации интерфейса ограничения (неявно) применяются. т. к. вы не можете вызвать этот метод иначе, чем через интерфейс. Но для неявной реализации — то есть, обыкновенного метода, который можно вызывать напрямую — неявное применение ограничений было бы слишком непонятным для пользователей класса.

---

По поводу первой части, сообщение об ошибке даёт нужную информацию:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter `T` must be contravariantly valid on `II<T>.M<V>()`. `T` is covariant.

Смотрите, `out`-параметр `T` является ковариантным. То есть, `II<Derived>` является подтипом `II<Base>`.

Пусть у нас есть класс

```
class C : II<Derived> { void M<V>() where V : Derived { } }
```

Тогда мы можем написать:

```
II<Base> ii = new C();
ii.M<Base>();
```

Но в объекте `C` у нас не может быть `Base` generic-параметром для M! То есть, как видите, `where V : T` подходит для контравариантных, но не ковариантных параметров, то есть, является *контравариантным использованием*.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Только вот наверное не "_Для неявной реализации интерфейса ограничения_", а "_Для **явной** реализации интерфейса ограничения_". Ну и второе предложение тоже заменить

Comment: @Qutrix: Спасибо! Вы правы, я перепутал в ответе. Исправил ответ в соответствии с вашим комментарием.